# Как определить границы склеенных ячеек в Excel листе, используя EPPlus?

Tags: excel, vb.net, epplus

Дано:
На листе имеется 15 колонок, известно что в 5-той колонке имеются склеенные по вертикали ячейки.
Используя библиотеку EPPlus, пытаюсь получить информацию о том, какие ячейки склеены, но добираясь до ячейки у которой `is_merge=True` я вижу в `cell.Start.Address` и `cell.End.Address` одно и тоже.

```
    Dim columns As Integer = 0

    Using package As New ExcelPackage(xlsx_file)

        Dim worksheet As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets(1)

        columns = worksheet.Dimension.Columns
        Dim rows As Integer = worksheet.Dimension.Rows

        For row = 1 To rows

            Dim is_merge As Boolean = worksheet.Cells(row, 5).Merge

            If is_merge = True Then

                Dim value As Object = worksheet.Cells(row, 5).Value
                Dim cell As ExcelRange = worksheet.Cells(row, 5)

                Dim start = cell.Start.Address
                Dim [end] = cell.End.Address

                Stop

            End If


        Next

    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменной `cell` присвоена одна ячейка - `Cells(row, 5)`, но не диапазон сцепленых ячеек, поэтому и адрес одинаковый.

В примерах ниже - сцепление в столбце. И второе примечание - в примерах смесь VBA и того, что в коде автора (надеюсь, там тоже есть операторы `Offset`, `MergeArea`... или аналогичные) :). Разберетесь.

Находим адрес последней ячейки в сцепленном диапазоне.

**Вариант 1**. Находим количество ячеек `i` в сцепленном диапазоне и смещаем фокус на `i - 1`. Но смещение в этом же столбце

```
Cells(row, 5).Offset(i - 1, 0).Address
```

получится от последней ячейки сцепленного диапазона, поэтому смещение применяем к ячейке соседнего (или любого другого) столбца:

```
i = Cells(row, 5).MergeArea.Cells.Count
Dim [end] = Cells(row, 4).Offset(i - 1, 1).Address
```

И все бы ничего, но если ячейка, на которую идет ссылка, тоже объединена с другими, будет ошибка определения адреса.

**Вариант 2** лишен этого недостатка. Находим первую ячейку после сцепленных, потом смещаем ее вверх на одну строку:

```
Dim temp As ExcelRange = worksheet.Cells(row, 5).Offset(1, 0)
Dim [end] = temp.Offset(-1,0).Address
```

**Вариант 3**. Без смещения. Определяем количество ячеек в сцепленном диапазоне и добавляем его к ссылке на строку:

```
i = Cells(row, 5).MergeArea.Cells.Count
Dim cellEnd As ExcelRange = worksheet.Cells(row + i - 1, 5)
Dim [end] = cellEnd.Address
```

Comment: Да по поводу одной ячейки а не диапазона, наверное стоит проверить, с другой стороны, при всем уважении, все эти манипуляции со смещением крайне сомнительны как решение вопроса, учитывая то что соседние ячейки могут быть тоже склеены. Либо я не понял как это работает.

Comment: А зачем смещение по горизонтали делать то? Ячейки склеены по вертикали а не по горизонтали.

Comment: По коду не увидел, в тексте пропустил... Учитывая замечания, изменил сообщение (теперь в примерах сцепление ячеек в столбце). Добавлен третий вариант.

Comment: MergeArea нету такого метода или свойства. Offset есть

Comment: Вариант 2 должен сработать. Третий лучше, но жаль...